# How to generate reusable ref for enum in Java Swagger 2

Tags: java, swagger, dropwizard

In a Dropwizard application with Swagger 2 interface descriptions, I get the following output in the `swagger.json` file for an object with an Enum type property.

```json
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "definitions" : {
    "Thing" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "color" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "enum" : [ "BLUE", "GREEN", "RED", "YELLOW" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The enum `Color` mentioned in the above example is exposed as type `string`. However, I would like it to be a reused ref, so something like this:

```json
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "definitions" : {
    "Color" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "enum" : [ "BLUE", "GREEN", "RED", "YELLOW" ]
    },
    "Thing" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "color" : {
          "$ref" : "#/definitions/Color"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For OpenAPI 3 there is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57079808): Just add the annotation `@Schema(enumAsRef = true)` on the defining enum. Is there something comparable in Swagger 2 so that I get the above output? Or do I need to migrate to OpenAPI 3?

Comment: Swagger 2 does not seem to be possible